# How to get correct mongo bulkWrite result if bulkWrite throws error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to get mongoose bulkWrite result when bulkWrite throws an error?

I searched the web for days, and all I could find is that the solution is to set `{ordered: false}`
but that did not solve anything.

For example, I have bulkWrite that looks like this:

```
try {
        let data = [{ ...some_data}, { ...some_data}, {...some_data}]

    let updateOps = data.map((item) => {
        return {
             updateOne: {
                     filter: { some_field: item.some_field },
                     update: item,
                     upsert: true,
                      },
                }
            })

        const result = await model.bulkWrite(updateOps, { ordered: false } )

} catch (e) {

    ... do something with error

}
```

And if everything goes well, as a result I get nModified, nUpserted etc like in mongoose docs.

But if for example bulkWrite throws error after 2nd update, it goes to catch block and I never can actually see the update result, or get count of items that were updated before error is thrown.

Is there any solution to continue with bulkWrite after error, or at least to get info about docs that were modified or upserted before the one that caused error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const bulkWriteOps = data.map((item) => {
    return {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { some_field: item.some_field },
            update: item,
            upsert: true
        }
    };
});

let bulkWritePromise = model.bulkWrite(bulkWriteOps, { ordered: false }).execute();

bulkWritePromise
    .then((result) => {
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error, "Error")
 });
```

Comment: more methods that you can call on result object https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.9/classes/BulkWriteResult.html#getInsertedIds

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot access the result because if there is an error it goes directly into catch block, so result is undefined.